# Handling same type exceptions separately in Python

Tags: python, exception

Say I have the following four variables:

```
>>> f1 = (print, 1, 2 ,3 ,4)
>>> f2 = (exit, 1, 2 ,3 ,4)
>>> f3 = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> f4 = 4
```

In a hypothetical program, I expect each of those variables to hold a tuple, whose first item should be the name of a function, and whose subsequent items should be said function's parameters, in order.

I could call a function stored in this way like so:

```
>>> f1[0](*f1[1:])
1 2 3 4
```

However, most of these variables are not in the excepted format, and I would like to be able to encapsulate the calling of them inside `try`/`except` blocks in order to handle those situations.

Now, even though the function calls of `f2`, `f3` and `f4` break for radically different reason, they all throw the same kind of exception, a `TypeError`:

```
>>> f2[0](*f2[1:])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __call__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
>>> f3[0](*f3[1:])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> f4[0](*f4[1:])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

So that doing a generic:

```
try:
    f[0](*f[1:])
except TypeError:
    # handle exception
```

Would not provide me with enough information to handle each exception accordingly.

What would be the correct way to differentiate between distinct exceptions of the same type in Python?

Answer (score 2):

So, you need to use a different method of calling than `function(*tuple)`. Here is an example of a function `fun_apply` that calls a particular function with positional and keyword arguments. It adds an explicit check to make sure that `args` is iterable and `kwargs` inherits from `collection.Mapping`.

```
from collections import Mapping

def fun_apply(f, args=None, kwargs=None):                                                                                
    if args is None:
        args = []
    if kwargs is None:
        kwargs = {}

    try:
        args = iter(args)
    except TypeError:
        # handle args being non-iterable
        pass

    if isinstance(kwargs, collections.Mapping):
        pass
    else:
        # handle kwargs being a non-mapping
        pass

    if hasattr(f, '__call__'):
        pass
    else:
        # handle f being non-callable
        pass

    try:
        f(*args, **kwargs)
    except TypeError as e:
        raise TypeError(e)
```

The other option is to process the `message` string explicitly, but this could have unintended consequences and the error messages themselves might differ between versions of Python.

Comment: I understand those approaches work in cases where I'm manually raising `TypeError` (or a subclass of it). How would they apply to situations where the exception is being raised without my direct input, such as in my example functions?

Comment: Right, if you enter the wrong number of arguments or unexpected keyword arguments, you will raise a `TypeError` and the body of your function will not be evaluated. However if you use something like `fun_apply`, you can catch this `TypeError` and throw a new exception, `TypeError` or otherwise, that wraps the called function.

Comment: But what if that's not what I want my `try`/`except` block to do in all cases? What if I only want to catch the case where a proper function (or callable) like `exit` is being called with too many (or too few) parameters, and want to print a warning when that happens, but still want my program to crash and burn when the first item of the tuple isn't callable (or the variable isn't a tuple at all)? How should I go about that? Is there any extra information I can gather from the exception object that would allow me to handle those situations properly?

Comment: Okay, I thought you just wanted to determine which function had thrown an exception ... for distinguishing different causes there are two options. If you use `fun_apply` or something similar you could add an explicit check that `args` and `kwargs` are iterable. You could also inspect the `e.message` string, but that is a bit messy.

Comment: Ah, I see what the misunderstanding was now. Is there anything in the phrasing of my question that made you believe that's what I wanted to know? If so, tell me because I would want to edit it. Also, if you could format your last comment as a new answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @zayora I saw several example expressions containing functions and jumped to the conclusion that you needed to distinguish between the functions rather than the different ways that your tuples could be malformed. I think the phrasing is fine. I'm still trying to look up whether the exception messages are standardized between different versions of python.